# Chrome Extension Still Running Despite Remote Deactivation Flag Set to False

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, async-await, fetch

I have a Chrome extension that I want to be able to deactivate remotely. I've set up a JSON file hosted on my server (https://a-cidm.github.io/pim/status.json) that contains a flag indicating whether the extension should be active or not:

```
{
    "extensionIsActive": false
}
```

In my extension's JavaScript code, I fetch this JSON file and check the extensionIsActive flag. If it's false, I want to deactivate the extension, which in this case means preventing certain functions (capturedData, loadFromLocalStorage, processText) from running.

Here's the relevant part of my code:
([full code](https://a-cidm.github.io/pim/code6.txt))

```
let extensionIsActive = true;

// Function to get extension status
async function getExtensionStatus() {
  const response = await fetch('https://a-cidm.github.io/pim/status.json');
  const data = await response.json();
  extensionIsActive = data.extensionIsActive;
}

// Function to update the state
function updateStatus(message) {
  const statusElement = document.getElementById('status');

  if (statusElement.innerHTML !== "") {
    message = "<br>" + message;
  }

  statusElement.innerHTML += message;
  statusElement.scrollTop = statusElement.scrollHeight; // To automatically scroll down
}

// Function to disable the functionality of the extension
function deactivateExtension() {
  updateStatus('Error 207.');
  // Extra Code
  return; // Exit the function
}

// Check the status of the extension each time it is opened
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
  await getExtensionStatus();
  if (!extensionIsActive) {
    deactivateExtension();
    return; // Exit the function
  }
});

  function loadFromLocalStorage() {
    if (!extensionIsActive) return;
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('capturedData');
    if (storedData) {
      return JSON.parse(storedData);
    }
    return [];
  }
  
  const capturedData = loadFromLocalStorage();
  
  document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    if (!inputText) return;
  
    const inputList = inputText.split('\n');
    let currentIndex = 1;
  
    for (const text of inputList) {
      updateProgress(currentIndex, inputList.length);
  // The rest of the code...
  });

function capturedData() {
  if (!extensionIsActive) return;
  // The rest of the code...
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  if (!extensionIsActive) return;
  // The rest of the code...
}

function processText() {
  if (!extensionIsActive) return;
  // The rest of the code...
}
```

However, even when extensionIsActive is false, the extension continues to function normally. There are no error messages in the JavaScript console.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the extension deactivates when extensionIsActive is false?

I've tried to implement a remote deactivation feature for my Chrome extension by fetching a JSON file from my server and checking a flag (extensionIsActive) in that file. If the flag is false, I want to deactivate the extension by preventing certain functions from running.

I expected that when extensionIsActive is false, the extension would stop functioning. Specifically, I expected the capturedData, loadFromLocalStorage, and processText functions to return immediately and not execute their usual code.

However, even when extensionIsActive is false, the extension continues to function normally. All the functions run as if extensionIsActive were true.

I've checked the JavaScript console for error messages, but there are none. I've also made sure that the URL for the JSON file is specified in the host_permissions section of my extension's manifest.json file.

I'm not sure what else to try to get the remote deactivation feature to work as expected.

Comment: Please describe where this code is running (e.g. content script?), what your extension does in general (what is "extension continues to function normally"), and maybe show your manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
Thank you for your time. The code in my extension's "popup.js" file is designed to automate searches on a specific portal. Even when extensionIsActive is false, the extension continues to function normally. This means that the capturedData, loadFromLocalStorage, and processText functions still run and perform their tasks. However, when extensionIsActive is false, I want these functions to return immediately without executing their usual code.

my manifest.json: [link](https://pastebin.com/0vB2pRE6)

Comment: Judging by `scripting` you inject code into the tab and I guess this code is what keeps running. You need to send the new value of the flag into that code. You can do it by using a global variable like `window.active` inside the injected code and setting it in executeScript with `args` parameter.